# Excel: I want to count the amount of times a set value comes up in several columns

Tags: excel

```
A1 A2 A3 A4
```

B1  2  3  2  4

B2  2  4  3  5

B3  4  2  3  2

B4  3  5  2  4

What Excel formula can I use to tell me how many the Total number "2" is in the columns of this simple spreadsheet. Or how many 3's. Or any set value.  For example Total numbers of 2  = ?, And put this calculate total into a cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a countif formula. In the countif formula you first specify the range, then the criteria. So if I am reading your example correctly it would look something like, "=countif(A1:B4,2)". That should work.